# Trouble with live communication with QProcess and VS C++

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I'm trying to establish a live communication between a QT program and a VS C++ program. However, I can read anything unless I close the writechannel in which I can't write anything anymore. Furthermore, the code I have now reads a continuous stream of output when I write one line to the VS C++ program when it should be waiting for the next input. Is there a way to establish synchronous communication with the two? What is wrong with my current program?

I've read documentation and can't seem to get a clear answer.

My Qt code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    process = new QProcess(this);
    connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readOutput()));
    //connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()),this,SLOT(readOutput()));
    process->setArguments(args);
    process->setProgram("C:\\Users\\chten\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\QProcess\\test\\Debug\\test.exe");
    process->start();
    process->waitForStarted();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}




void MainWindow::readOutput() {
    ui->input->append(process->readAllStandardOutput());
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_pressed()
{
    process->write("left");
    process->waitForBytesWritten();
    process->closeWriteChannel();

}
```

My C++ code:

```
    cout << "waiting for response..." << endl;
    string input_line;
    //getline(cin, input_line);
    //cout << input_line << endl;
    while (true) {
        getline(cin, input_line);
        cout << input_line << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i<9999999; i++){}
    }
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you never write a *line* to the child process, you just have...

```
process->write("left");
```

No newline.  In the meantime the child is executing...

```
getline(cin, input_line);
```

waiting for the newline delimiter.

The reason closing the write channel appears to work is that it will cause the `getline` call in the child to receive an end-of-file condition and return.  However, it will also set the [`eofbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) in the input stream's state causing further calls to `getline` to return immediately: hence the `"continuous stream of output"` you refer to.

Try changing the implementation of `MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_pressed` to...

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_pressed ()
{
    process->write("left\n");
    process->waitForBytesWritten();
}
```

and change the child's source code to...

```
std::cout << "waiting for response..." << endl;
std::string input_line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, input_line)) {
    std::cout << input_line << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i<9999999; i++) {
    }
}
return 0;
```

(All untested.)

As an aside, using `Qt` functions such as `waitFoStarted`, `waitForBytesWritten` etc. can be convenient but should be avoided.  Far better to connect to and handle the various [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#signals) available.